# What does the '->' operator signify in Objective C?

Tags: java, objective-c, xcode, operators

XCode just corrected my use of the **`.`** operator to the **`->`** operator.

I have searched around to find a definition or documentation for the **`->`** operator but could find any.

I am trying to emulate a Java-style of instance variable. Specifically I am initializing an instance with a provided **`configuration`** object which I want to keep around for subsequent use after the method **`initializeService`** has executed.

A good answer to this question would provide a comparison with Java instance variable declaration and subsequent assignment via an instance method.

**Code before XCode correction:**

```
#import "MY_Service.h"
#import "MY_Configuration.h"

@implementation MY_Service {

    MY_Configuration *configuration;

}

-(void)initializeService:(MY_Configuration *)configuration
{
    self.configuration = configuration;

}


@end
```

**Code after XCode correction:**

```
#import "MY_Service.h"
#import "MY_Configuration.h"

@implementation MY_Service {

    MY_Configuration *configuration;

}

-(void)initializeService:(MY_Configuration *)configuration
{
    self->configuration = configuration;

}


@end
```

Comment: change `configuration` to be a property instead of an ivar.

Comment: Note that you don't have to use self at all to reference ivars.

Comment: Objective-C instance variables are ordinarily prefixed with an underscore. If you change your declaration to follow this convention you can rewrite your assignment as `_configuration = configuration`.

Comment: @jlehr - Thanks. I made your change. My assumption is that I have properly scoped the configuration object as an instance variable and not as a property. Below an answer suggests that I make it a property. In Java it would be an instance variable that is kept private after initializeService is called. (i.e. there would be no getter or setter). Have I made the right choice?

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi There are no absolutes here, but property declarations do have certain advantages, for example allowing you to specify additional things such as `copy` semantics for memory management, atomicity, etc. But your code correctly declares a private instance variable that would work as you expect.

Comment: @jlehr - Thanks again. You've answered my question. If you copy & paste your comments as an answer then all the answer booty is yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C instance variables are ordinarily prefixed with an underscore. If you change your declaration to follow this convention you can rewrite your assignment as

```
_configuration = configuration;
```

With respect to whether it would be better to declare a property or an instance variable, there are no absolutes here, but property declarations do have certain advantages. Some examples would be allowing you to specify additional things such as `copy` semantics for memory management, atomicity, etc. But your code correctly declares a private instance variable that would work as you expect.

Answer (score 4):

The `->` means the same thing in Objective-C that it does in C.  That is:

```
a->b
```

is equivalent to

```
(*a).b
```

Comment: I think it is not completely the same when the "modern" Objective-C runtime is used. The ivars do not have fixed offsets to the beginning of the struct anymore to solve the fragile base class problem. Compare http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/01/27/objc_explain_Non-fragile_ivars.html.

Comment: @MartinR - A quick (hence incomplete) check shows `iVar`, `self->iVar` and `(*self).iVar` all produce the same code. I.e. the implementation detail that both `.` and `->` are no longer using fixed offsets is correctly handled by the compiler as it should be and the equivalence still holds. Indeed I don't think fixed offsets were ever part of the C Standard definition of member access.

Comment: @CRD: My point (perhaps badly expressed) is that `->` does not do exactly the same thing for C structs vs Objective-C classes. I am quite sure that members in C structs have a fixed offset that is determined at compile time (and can be determined with the `offsetof()` macro from stddef.h). For Objective-C objects, `obj->_ivar` does a double indirection (as explained in Greg Parker's blog).

Comment: @MartinR - Understood. Similarly my point is that the *meaning* is the same, member (field or ivar) access and the equivalence holds, just as Carl stated. That the *implementation* differs doesnt change that. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

`->` is used to access instance variables, the same way it's used to access member variables of a pointer in C or C++.

In the code you provided, you declared `configuration` as an instance variable. If you wanted to use the dot operator, you should have declared it as a property, which is what you really should have done from the beginning.

Comment: A Hassan: Why should it be a property if I don't want to access it from outside the instance? Thanks.

Comment: I think of it as a habit. Declaring a property doesn't take much space  than declaring an ivar, and in modern Objective-C it's automatically synthesized. The cost of a call to them isn't costly, unless you're doing some heavy optimization. It gives you the chance to add behaviour, like strong or weak referencing and atomicity. **The point is**, it's not tedious to write and it gives you capabilities.